# SAN disk Write/Read speed

Tags: windows, storage-area-network

We are currently having some issues transferring large files (100-800 GB) from one Windows 2003 server to another.  They are all virtualized and on SAN partitions so we are trying to narrow down the gap between Networking, ESX, or SAN.  Preliminary testing does not indicate Network performance, so we are moving on to testing write/read speeds of the SAN partitions by the OS.  My question is this:

1. Does anyone have a good windows tool or CLI command to test read/write on a partition?

Comment: you don't really give enough info on your setup for a helpful answer

Comment: Not asking for help fixing the issue, too many parameters that I am not sure about yet. I was giving background to explain why I wanted a tool to check R/W on Disk Partitions, Specifically SAN.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have been useing [**IOMeter**](http://www.iometer.org/) successfully. Have you optimized your SAN Config according to VMware´s [**Whitepaper (PDF)**](http://www.vmware.com/pdf/vi3_301_201_san_cfg.pdf). Look for "Setting Maximum Queue Depth for HBAs"...

Comment: Ill give the IOmeter a look. Our VM dudes have already been through SAN Configs for the host to make sure it is inline with all the other ESX hosts on the network.  No problems found so far.

Comment: +1 for IOmeter. It's a great general-purpose IO measurement tool.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, So I have been doing more research and I think that the Microsoft tool SQLIO is going to be what will give the most info for my needs.   I am going to start this tonight and let everyone know how it goes as far as usefulness. I found a [fairly good tutorial onlin](http://sqlserverpedia.com/wiki/SAN_Performance_Tuning_with_SQLIO)e tha tI am going to follow.  If anyone else has any ideas, please let me know!